# Flatten list items that have a N depth list in themselves with no use of recursion in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, recursion

### **I want to**

sort N depth items in a single list in `C#`. Each of the items has a N depth list in itself. The model looks like this below.

```
TestModel model = new TestModel
        {
            Name = "Model",
            Nested = new List<TestModel>
            {
                new TestModel {
                    Name = "T1"
                },
                new TestModel {
                    Name = "T2"
                },
                new TestModel {
                    Name = "T3"
                },
                new TestModel {
                    Name = "T4-Nested01",
                    Nested = new List<TestModel> {
                        new TestModel {
                            Name = "T4-Nested01-T1",
                        },
                        new TestModel {
                            Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02",
                            Nested = new List<TestModel> {
                                new TestModel {
                                    Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03",
                                    Nested = new List<TestModel> {
                                        new TestModel {
                                            Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03-T1"
                                        },
                                        new TestModel {
                                            Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03-T2"
                                        },
                                        new TestModel {
                                            Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03-T3"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                new TestModel {
                                    Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T2"                                        
                                },
                                new TestModel {
                                    Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T3"                                        
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new TestModel {
                            Name = "Nested01-T2",
                        },
                        new TestModel {
                            Name = "Nested01-T3"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        // model looks like this.
        // ㄴ Name = "Model"
        // ㄴ Nested Count 4
            // ㄴ [0] TestModel T1
            // ㄴ [1] TestModel T2
            // ㄴ [2] TestModel T3
            // ㄴ [3] TestModel T4
                // ㄴ Name = "T4-Nested01"
                // ㄴ Nested Count 4
                    // ㄴ [0] TestModel T4-Nested01-T1
                    // ㄴ [1] TestModel T4-Nested01-T2
                        // ㄴ Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02"
                        // ㄴ Nested Count 3
                            // [0] TestModel T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1
                                // ㄴ Name = "T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03"
                                // ㄴ Nested Count 3
                                    // [0] TestModel T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03-T1
                                    // [1] TestModel T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03-T2
                                    // [2] TestModel T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T1-Nested03-T3
                                // [1] TestModel T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T2
                                // [2] TestModel T4-Nested01-T2-Nested02-T3
                    // ㄴ [2] TestModel
                    // ㄴ [3] TestModel
```

### **I need**

a single list to make it easier to search a specific element by some properties from the sorted list. I already have a recursive algorithm to achieve that goal. But I'd like to use non-recursive solution.

### Question

1. Which non-recursive algorithms should I use for best performance?
2. Which data structures should I use for the simplest code?

Giving me an idea will suffice, or if you could tweak an alternative algorithm for me, that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use recursion to iterate a graph, it seems like you are not using any data structures to perform the traversal, but you are actually using an implicit/inherent data structure: the Stack. Therefore it follows that to perform the same type of traversal without recursion, one would need a stack.

In C# you can use a Stack, the 'yield return' keyword and a delegate to create a linq-like extension method that will perform this graph traversal in a very convenient and reusable way. A rough outline of an implementation is below:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while(stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        yield return current;
        foreach(var child in selector(current))
        {
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
foreach(var item in model.Flatten(t=>t.Nested))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

You will want to add some null checks and optionally, checks to prevent infinite cycles (if a child in your graph contained a ancestor, this algorithm would get stuck in an infinite loop, while a recursive algorithm would stack overflow)

This type of graph traversal is known as 'depth-first'. You can implement a 'breadth-first' version by simply swapping out the stack for a queue.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for the tips and the clear explanations. That's just what I needed to be informed. It looks like I need to implement BFS ! ( because the nested list should take the lower priority in the sorted, single list. ) I really appreciate your answer ! Two thumbs up !!